# Adjusting pseudo-elements width

Tags: html, css, width

How could I adjust the width of the pseudo-element without setting padding/margin on the .item-class? Lets say I want 20px free on each side of the border.

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="item">
         <p>Box 1</p>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
         <p>Box 2</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.item:after {
     width: 100%; // ?
     height: inherit;
     position: absolute;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     content: " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `left`/`right` like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.item:after {
  left:20px;
  right:20px;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Box 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Box 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```